# why use static "constants" instead of the actual value?

Tags: c++, c

I am looking at a code for a least square method, and I came across the following few lines:

```
static double one = 1.0;
static double p1 = 0.1;
static double p5 = 0.5;
...
```

and I was wondering why someone would define a `static` for `1.0`. I can understand having something for `pi`, for example, but for trivial mathematical values like `1.0` and `0.1`, etc.? I think it will make the code less readable, but it might have some other benefit(s) that I'm missing.

So, is there a reason for these definitions? or, if it is not being used with modern codes, were there any reasons for this with old compilers? I know that the code that I'm looking at was translated to C/C++ from FORTRAN. Were there any reasons for this in FORTRAN?

Comment: What is worse, they aren't even `const`... That can be useful if someone needs a pointer/reference to this number in some API call, but using it directly in formulas is weird indeed.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't use `const`.

Comment: I misunderstood the question ...sorry folks..

Comment: Does the code do things like `foo(&one)`? I think this might be related to Fortran's parameter passing rules.

Comment: @user2357112 I can't see any uses other than simple math, `-one`, `one + ...`, and stuff like that.

Comment: Some related history at Software Engineering.SE about what old Fortran compilers allowed: [Ever change the value of 4?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254799/ever-change-the-value-of-4-how-did-this-come-into-hayes-thomas-quiz)

Comment: Sounds like it's just dumb, then.

Comment: @hardmath So this is just for sticking to the original FORTRAN? First time I saw it my thought went to "it might have some optimization benefits".

Comment: Fortran is used and still is for scientific purposes often requiring a degree of precision so maybe for some purposes you might see that or for an exactly formatted data. Also declaring `double one = 1.0;` at one point in a program may be faster to load into arithmetic registers than if it has to create a memory spot to move into it first. So perhaps it's for performance practices. I personally wouldn't consider it bad practice given the complexity of software and compilation control (who knows what it could be doing), I would want my variables allocated inline.

Comment: Addressing the question title alone: Suppose you are using the value 8 for `arrows` and the value 8 for `targets` and you have also assumed there are 8 bits in a byte. You then want to modify the code so that you use 9 for `arrows`. You'll need to hunt through the program and it will be painful to figure out which of the many occurrences of `8` are the ones that need changing. But you can use `const` variable to define your limits *once* only, and any change takes effect throughout the code (where in scope).

Comment: Also just in case your interested here is java code which computes the volume of fluid inside a capsule tank given a height of fluid inside it (There is no algebraic solution to it strangely enough) using Newton's method. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376569/find-the-value-of-h-from-a-kepler-type-equation/1381526#1381526

Comment: @triple_r:  Yes, this has the earmarks of code pedantically converted from Fortran to C/C++, and the declaration has more to do with scope of the named constants than with enforcing constancy.  For early Fortran compilers there was a challenge of memory economy, so I'm guessing there could have been an optimization motive, but lost on/irrelevant to the C/C++ programmer who converted it.

Comment: "I'm looking at was translated to C/C++ from FORTRAN" Are you really this code both as a C and separately as C++ source code?  The best answer depends on the target language.  This post would have been much better if it had not selected more than one language as the answers differ.

Comment: What version of FORTRAN is being translated? FORTRAN floating point literals default to single precision and the syntax for double precision literals is somewhat clunky. Compare `one` versus `1.0_dp`.

Comment: @Dunes Unfortunately, I don't know the version of FORTRAN code. Though, the original code was written back in the 80s if that helps. That makes sense though, thanks.

Comment: @chux The code was translated to C originally, but I'm using a C++ compiler so I thought I should add that tag as well. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Dunes I think I found the answer and it is very similar to what you mentioned, they wanted to have the code be compilable in both floating point and double precision, so having a single place to change `float` to `double` (or whatever the FORTRAN version is) and recompile was a lot more reasonable than having to replace all literal numbers.

Comment: I haven't read all the comments and answers, but AFAIK it was very common practice to set constants like "zero = 0.0d0, one = 1.0d0, two = 2.0d0" in old Fortran77 codes (I also did that before sometimes). In my case, this was for more readability, not for optimization. I think you can find similar examples in many old library codes (like in netlib etc).

Comment: An example is [zheev](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d9a/group__complex16_h_eeigen_ga70c041fd19635ff621cfd5d804bd7a30.html#ga70c041fd19635ff621cfd5d804bd7a30) in Lapack. This is useful particularly for the imaginary unit "i" (I used "zi = (zero, one)" very often before...)

Comment: @roygvib Thanks! Your answer makes a lot of sense. Especially the complex number short-hand. FYI, the code that I'm looking was translated from a portion of MINPACK.

Answer (score 6):

> I know that the code that I'm looking at was translated to C/C++ from
>   FORTRAN. Were there any reasons for this in FORTRAN?

FORTRAN uses pass-by-reference for all subroutine parameters.  However, unlike other languages with pass-by-reference, it still lets you pass “rvalues” as parameters.  Behind the scenes, the FORTRAN compiler converts code like:

```
CALL SUBFOO(X + Y, 4)
```

to code like

```
TEMP1 = X + Y
TEMP2 = 4
CALL SUBFOO(TEMP1, TEMP2)
```

And this is exactly what your C++ code is doing: Creating variables in order to pass a pointer (or reference) to a subroutine FORTRAN-style.

Of course, this is not idiomatic C or C++.  Normally, you'd pass a `double` *by value*.

(Code samples copied from my answer to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254799/ever-change-the-value-of-4-how-did-this-come-into-hayes-thomas-quiz).)

Comment: Thanks, so was there a performance gain by defining `four = 4` and then using `call sub(four) ... call sub2(four) ...` instead of using literal `4.0`? Is it still the case? or do new compilers take care of this?

Comment: This was my hypothesis, but apparently most uses of these variables aren't actually for function parameters. It looks like they just mechanically replaced every literal, maybe because it was easier than specifically targeting function parameters. Also, [Fortran argument association isn't quite pass by reference](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/03/31/doctor-fortran-in-ive-come-here-for-an-argument); there are some weird special cases.

Comment: @user2357112 that's true, except for one line: `temp = mp_dmax1(zero, one - temp*temp);` the rest are not used as arguments for any calls, as far as I can see.

Comment: @triple_r: `one - temp*temp` - well, that puts another big hole in this hypothesis, because if the point of this was to preserve the original Fortran parameter passing semantics, the `one - temp*temp` temporary would have to have been saved to a variable. It sounds like these `zero`, `one`, etc. variables are just 100% pointless, then.

Comment: @user2357112 I think I know why they are done like that now. As someone mentioned in the comment to the question, it was to allow converting the code to be run in both single and double precision very easily. So having all the numbers in the code be assigned to variables, it is easy to change the precision (for example, changing `double one = 1.0` to `float one = 1.0` instead of changing all `1,0`s to `1.0f`).

Answer (score 5):

Use of

```
static double one = 1.0;
static double p1 = 0.1;
static double p5 = 0.5;
```

does not make much sense to me. It would make sense had the variables been named with something more meaningful. I see the value of something like:

```
static double defaultCoefficient = 1.0;
static double defaultRateOfIncrease = 0.1;
static double defaultRatio = 0.5;
```

In the second set, use of the variables in code is a lot more meaningful than using the corresponding constants.

It would be more meaningful to make them constant.

```
static double const defaultCoefficient = 1.0;
static double const defaultRateOfIncrease = 0.1;
static double const defaultRatio = 0.5;
```

---

> I know that the code that I'm looking at was translated to C/C++ from FORTRAN.

If the translation was done by a program, it's understandable why the variables are named the way they are.

If the translation was done by a human, they probably followed some guideline on how to move things fast, and not necessarily create meaningful variable names by understanding the code.

Comment: That makes sense, but in this code, it is the literal `1.0`, so for example, when they want to use the identity matrix, they initialize it by: `diag[i] = one;`.

Comment: These should still be made into constants.

Comment: `one` is 100% silly, no question about that. But to be fair, names like `p1` and `p5` can make sense if they refer to something like variables *p1* or *p5* from a scientific paper being implemented. Of course, if they stand for "[zero] point 1" and "[zero] point 5", they're just as silly as `one`.

Comment: Even more useful than const : `constexpr`

Comment: @Angew they stand for "[zero] point 1" etc, the code goes on to define `p25`, `p75`, and `p0001`.

Comment: Just something I think is "poor spent time for everyone" is when asker ask's something and doesn't provide all the information and someone post answer and the asker shoots the answer down by pulling a curve ball out of ...

Comment: @marshalcraft I'm sorry, but I thought I had provided all the necessary bits. I was just wondering why there are variables/constants defined and used instead of literal mathematical constants. Would appreciate if you let me know how to improve the question to not have it be "poor spent time for everyone".

Comment: I was joking mostly. It is well asked.

Comment: Heck of a joke, @marshal

Comment: "If the translation was done by a human", that human may not have wanted to replace all occurrences of `p1` to `1.0`, just in case there was a `p10` lurking in the dark.

Comment: @RadLexus, that's not the real issue. The choice of picking between `p1` and a more meaningful variable name is the issue.

Comment: I don't know FORTRAN but the consensus seems to be that they were named so *in the original source*. So my point is, why change them when converting to C and risk breaking the code?

Comment: @RadLexus, that makes sense.

Comment: There's also the intermediate option that the program was initially converted from FORTRAN to C++ by machine, and then a human began to “clean up” the code but never finished the job.

Answer (score 5):

One case where I've seen this used is on some (older, embedded) platforms using a Harvard architecture.

Say I have a (external library) function that takes a pointer as argument:

```
void Foo(double *Bar);
```

If i want to pass a constant to this function I obviously cannot write it directly. I have to do it like in the opening post so I can take the address of `one` for example.

```
Foo(&one);
```

On some Harvard platforms `const` values are put in program ROM or flash memory instead of RAM, so that would not work as you'd be taking the ROM address instead of the required RAM address.

Making it a global (static) variable is then done so it is initialized once in the startup code (value copied from ROM to RAM once) in stead of every time it is needed by making it a automatic variable.

A niche use case I admit.

Comment: Does the C standard allow such a memory model?  I know that it allows code pointers to be in a difference address space than data pointers (necessary for some x86-16 memory models), but can it disallow taking a non-const `T*` to a global `const T` object, even if the object is never modified through that pointer?

Comment: @dan04: Found this: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/EXP05-C.+Do+not+cast+away+a+const+qualification . Seems that casting away the `const` is UB. Should not compile without the cast (verified on gcc with `-pendantic-errors`).

Answer (score 3):

No, that constant is silly. If for no other reason than *it's not actually a constant*.

Comment: Can you add a bit more explanation on this topic?

Comment: What more explanation do you need? See, this is why opinion-based posts are not allowed here. I shouldn't really have answered!

Comment: No it's great that you answered..it helps but I am just asking ..static variables are not contant this is what you said right? Which it is not ..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I suppose that you could back up your assertion of non-constantness with an example showing how this could be broken. That way more readers would be able to get your point.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri: I don't understand what you mean by "an example showing how this could be broken". The questions asks about constants, but the declarations shown aren't constants; period! That's what I'm saying.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, sorry, that was my bad. I made a mistake reading the code, because having them be `static const` made more sense to me. I appreciate the answer, and it seems that with modern languages and compilers, it is, as you said, not necessary to do those definitions.

Comment: Silly me. I confused it with one of the answers. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a good reason to do this, and it involves the software development process itself.

Let's say you have a translation unit that invokes some function with some numeric parameter, naturally you'd make it a constant:

```
static const double epsilon = 1.e-3;
```

Nice, clean code. But now you realize that the epsilon you set isn't all that good and you need a better one. You don't really have a sure way to determine what it should be, so you go for some trial and error:

```
static const double epsilon = 1.e-4;
```

You rebuild you program. And it still isn't good. If you change it again you'd have to wait for the build to finish, and it can take a while on some non-trivial projects. What to do?

Well, debuggers let you change the value of variables, so long as they reside in memory (and not eliminated like true constants are). So we do the following:

```
static double epsilon = 1.e-4;
```

Now we set a breakpoint somewhere in that file. And we can modify `epsilon` without rebuilding our program every time. We end up saving precious development time. And we find a proper value in no-time.

Do we leave it non-`const`? No. This is a constant, and therefore we mark it as `const` before checking our code in. Leaving it non-const is a code smell. There is no further purpose to this.

Comment: Though I like the point about variable vs. constant for debugging purposes, I personally dislike the ideology of turning c syntax into object orientated like principles. For example I always disliked the way they typically teach O.O.P. where I'm supposed to think, "oh a dog is an object naturally..." then proceed with objected orientated programming. To me a constant has no further implications than it's function in the programming language and how it will effect the execution of that program. To me I would use a constant for a data that WILL not change for the lifespan of the software.

Comment: @marshalcraft - *"the ideology of turning c syntax into object orientated like principles"* I'm not sure I follow. A constant should be designated as a constant. C++ does it with `const`, and C with macros. There is no ideology other than enforcing a certain design.

Comment: Again I wouldn't make any significant connection between the syntactic declaration modifier and the word constant. One has a mathematical/physics meaning the other pertains to algorithm and much more explicitly.

Comment: Again I could see constant being used for maybe something like a program version number or anything that will not change programmatically. Function easily benefits programmatically defined 'constants' in many cases. So while your adhoc design practice certainly has merit in some imaginable use case I'm am sure, I think far more often it's a tool for business project managers and analyst to manage people, not software as many design practices don't relate to a quantifiable standard but interpretations of those in a management position ie. "code readability".

Comment: @marshalcraft - Have you been part of many large software projects? I'm wondering where the scorn for all things related to software design comes from.